# Chain Chronicle viewing order?

Tags: chain-chronicle

What is the best order to watch the 3 movies and the TV series of *Chain Chronicle*?

Is there any part that can be skipped (i.e. a movie is a compilation of the first 6 episodes, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

**The 12 episodes of the TV series retells the same story of the movie trilogy, each divided into 4 episodes.**

[The "Chapter List" table from Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%81%E3%82%A7%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AD%E3%83%8B%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AB#.E5.90.84.E8.A9.B1.E3.83.AA.E3.82.B9.E3.83.88) shows the overlapping between each volume of the movie with the TV episodes: episode 1-4 (vol. 1), episode 5-8 (vol. 2).

A [Reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/5mubpn/chain_chronicle_tv_vs_movie/) seems to reach the same conclusion,

> I saw the TV's first episode. It was a recap of the movie.
>   They probably just split the movie into parts and showed it as TVs.

And finally, [Theron Martin's review on AnimeNewsNetwork](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/review/chain-chronicle/the-light-of-haecceitas/movie-1/.111091),

> *Chain Chronicle: The Light of Haecceitas* is the first of a trilogy of movies being released once a month between December 2016 and February 2017. A TV series version is also airing during the Winter 2017 season, but based on its first two episodes, the TV series is just going to be the movies chopped up into 20-minute segments with an opener, closer, and a small intro and recap added in to smooth out the runtime. (Crunchyroll, which is streaming both versions, has taken the unusual practice of subdividing the movie version into those 20-25 minute segments, presumably so viewers know which parts of the movie match up with which TV episodes.) So this review could be seen as covering the first movie in a trilogy or the first four episodes of a one-cour series.